# Div collapses on ng-show

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-show

I have something like the following:

```
<div>
    <h4 data-ng-show='showMe'>I am showing</h4>
</div>
```

The height of the containing div is being adjusted depending on whether the h4 element is shown or is hidden.

Is there a way to make it so that the div has a constant height? Would I use min-height or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
  <div>
      <h4><span data-ng-show='showMe'>I am showing</span>&nbsp;</h4>
   </div>
```

Comment: The first did not work for me but your second suggestion did.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `min-height` rule to the parent `<div>`. The docs for `ng-show` state that the directive adds or removes the `.ng-hide` class which:

> The .ng-hide CSS class is predefined in AngularJS and sets the display style to none (using an !important flag)